# pandas-datareader extract price value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a list of the prices based in a DateTimeIndex, but since the column doesn't have a name how can I extract this value?

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
start_date = datetime(2002,1,1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
fx = pdr.get_data_fred("GOLDPMGBD228NLBM", start_date, end_date)
```

And I would like to retrieve a list from the values from the fx variable.

This is the current dataframe model:

```
In [41]: fx.head()                                                
Out[41]: 
            GOLDPMGBD228NLBM
DATE                        
2002-01-01               NaN
2002-01-02            278.35
2002-01-03            278.80
2002-01-04            277.75
2002-01-07            278.60
```

I expect something like this:

```
x = []
x = fx['Prices']
print(x)
['NaN', 278.35, 278.80, 277.75, 278.60]
```

Since I will work with many symbols I would like to handle it in a proper way.

Comment: Since that reader can return multiple prices depending on the codes you give it, it returns those codes as columns names... can you not either rename it or access it via `fx['GOLDPMGBD228NLBM']` ?

Comment: @JonClements I can do something like this a = [ x for x in fx['GOLDPMGBD228NLBM']  ]

Comment: Well, if you want it as a list then use `fx['GOLDPMGBD228NLBM'].tolist()`but then you lose all the advantages of having it as a DateTime index'd `pandas.Series` object...